# Logic Help: Calculating primes of a range of numbers with multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I've been tasked to calculate prime numbers using multiple threads. The user provides a range of numbers, and how many threads to use to find the prime numbers.

So for example, the range is 2 to 100 inclusive and we want to use 3 threads.

What I want to happen is the following:

```
Thread 1 found  2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31
Thread 2 found  37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67
Thread 3 found  71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Each thread is going to need to be supplied a start range and an end range. I have determined that a data structure would be the most appropriate for this, such as:

```
typedef struct Data{
    int start;
    int end;
}Data;
```

I can't figure out how to create these sub-ranges. I know I'll have to divide the max end range by how many threads we want, and getting the first threads range is easy but I'm lost after that. This seems like a simple issue that I am making entirely too complicated.

This is where I'm at:

```
int start, end, nthreads, div;

start = atoi(argv[1]);
end = atoi (argv[2]);
nthreads = atoi (argv[3]);
div = end/nthreads;

for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
    if (i == 0){
        //first iteration, start is start and end is the div
        data.start = start;
        data.end = div;
    }
    else{
        //this is where I am lost
        data.start = ??
        data.end = div*i;
    }

    //create the thread with our data
    //calculations is handled in threadCreate()
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, threadCreate, (void*)data);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding the multithreading tag (or the like) to get better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you want to remove the if (i==0) and simply set this:

```
data.start = start + div * i
data.end = start + div * (i + 1) - 1;
```

Be cautious though, you may want to redefine `div` as `(end-start) / nbthreads`.

You will then quickly realize that some ranges are harder to find prime numbers.

I would recommend using OpenMP which is made exactly for this kind of usage. This would simplify your threading by automatically splitting your `for` loop. This would allow you to easily use a dynamic task assignation scheme which will automatically balance thread assignation of easier and harder ranges in order to end the computation faster.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your else you are putting

```
data.end=div*i;
```

but you initialized you i with 0 so when else statement would be executed for the first time then **data.end** will have the value equals to **div**. And take

```
div = (end-start)/nthreads;
```

Try something like

```
else{
        data.start = (div)*(i))+1;
        data.end = data.start+div-1;
    }
```

Comment: I guess (start - end) will probably not do what you want! :) Furthermore, the +1 will make you skip the first number (start)

Comment: @Soravux oh by mistake:), thanx. And why would it skip, i have only suggested the else block.

Comment: You're right, missed your else block, sorry. But the last element of the last block will be outside the range (end + 1)... In fact, I guess you miss a data.start = (start - 1) + div * i + 1 [There is an extraneous parenthesis in your code], otherwise you would always start from 0. If it is the case, you have (div * i + 1 ) + div as end value, which will end up one after the end range...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to go about it:

a) split into even-sized blocks
b) split into interleaved blocks

e.g. start = 10, end = 90, n = 3 threads

you could either go:

```
thread1 = 10,11,12,13,...
thread2 = 40,41,42,43,...
thread3 = 70,71,72,73,...
```

or

```
thread1 = 10, 13, 16, 19, ...
thread2 = 11, 14, 17, 20, ...
thread3 = 12, 15, 18, 21, ...
```

Comment: Splitting into interleaved blocks will ensure threads will all end approximately at the same time. Even-sized blocks will get one thread running way longer than the rest.